# DIsk Image shows larger size unmounted then when mounted. How to fix

Tags: disk-utility, dmg

I have an encrypted dmg (Mac OS Extended Journaled) read/write and it shows a size of of 768.46 GB unmounted but only has a mounted capacity of 665.72 GB. I think something may have been corrupted when I resized it from 500GB to 650GB. I attempted through disk utility, which proceeded to appear to freeze, so I let it go for about 15 minutes and then I checked the log and it said "resize successful". I then proceeded to check the capacity of the image mounted and it still said 500GB. So next i tried resizing through `hdutil` which led me to where I am now. Unmounted size of 768.46 GB but a 665.72 GB capacity. Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: Same question here, except I didn't get any "resize successful" message. Disk Utility didn't freeze either.

Comment: Strange, I still have not found a fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

1. Open Disk Utility.
2. In the left-hand panel, select the disk image you would like to resize (the DMG file), then click the **Resize Image** button in the toolbar, and then enter the new size. Click **Log** to ensure that it resized successfully.
3. Click **Open** to mount the volume. (You may also mount the volume manually by opening the disk image in the Finder.) Select the volume in the left-hand panel. Notice how the volume's **Total Capacity** is unchanged. This is where you got stuck.
4. Select the disk image again (not the volume). Now there are new tabs available. Click the tab labeled **Partition**. This essentially allots different partitions of storage space to the disk image. Select the volume you would like to resize and drag the *... draggy thing?* or manually enter in a size. Then click **Apply**. Check the log to ensure the partition was resized successfully.
5. Select the volume in the left-hand panel. Check to ensure its **Total Capacity** is the correct size.

That's it! Now you can add more files to the volume. Remember to eject the volume when done.

Comment: Wow, not sure how i missed that. Great job figuring this out. Thanks